# How to load Hugginface model on CPU?

Tags: nlp, huggingface

My system runs out of memory on GPU. But I want just to test if it works and want to load it on CPU. How do I do that?
Adding `device = torch.device(‘cpu’)` before loading model doesn’t help
It crashes here:

```
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
    config.base_model_name_or_path,
    quantization_config=bnb_config,
    device_map="auto",
    trust_remote_code=True,
)
```

Comment: I have the same question and no one seems to know the answer